# How to get to the end of a line in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, intellij-idea

Is there a way to get the cursor to the end of the current line? That is, without using the End key, Ctrl + Left/Right or the mouse. It's time consuming to get to the end of the line when there's some code after the cursor.
eg.

In a strings.xml file, the  end tag is automatically generated and after inserting the value in between the tags, how would one get to the end of that line in order to press return and go to the new line?

```
<string name="hello_world"> Hello World | </string>
```

here, "|" = cursor

Similarly, despite android-studio's smart code auto-completion feature, it's common to get stuck behind a semi-colon/pair of parenthesis. In such cases, is there a quicker way to get to the end of the statement/block?

Comment: cmd+right arrow. also, https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf

Comment: But it moves the cursor 1 word at a time.

Comment: no it does not. that would be option+arrow

Comment: I doesn't work on windows.

Comment: You have a key on your keyboard... It's written **End** on it. Press it.

Comment: I don't think you read the question properly. Using the mouse would be faster than pressing that key.

Comment: @chaosifier probably because you don't have a cmd key. But there would be no way for me to know that until you said it, is there? (Anyway, the link I gave is mac-specific, but the windows equivalent also exists, and is not really hard to find)

Comment: a much quicker solution would have been to go to `settings -> keymap` and search for whatever action you are trying to perform. Examples include `move caret to end of line`, `move caret to end of block`, `move caret to text end`

Comment: @njzk2 I just downloaded the cheat-sheet for windows and i found  a lot of other handy shortcuts too. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I didn't know that feature existed. Thanks again !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

tl;dr use `Shift`+`Enter`

The title of your question asks how to get to the end of a line but in your question you mention wanting to get to the end of a line because automatically inserted characters are preventing you from hitting return to get to the next line.

All the other answers only solve half your problem. This command starts a new line and puts your cursor on it regardless of your cursor's current position in the line:

`Shift`+`Enter`

Here's an example of it being used:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Just Press End key on keyboard. and cursor will jump to end of line.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> for *end*

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> for *start*

Comment: And suddenly now i know a dozen ways to do it. Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Using the keyboard combination `Ctrl + [` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This will take you to the end of the line and automatically add a semicolon
CTRL + SHIFT + Enter

Answer (score 0):

**Shift + End** is the shortcut to move cursor to the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows Laptop the commands to go to the beginning and end of a line are:

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

File > Settings > Keymap (<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

- Type "end" in search
- Locate "Move Caret to Line End" under "Editor Actions"
- Double click assigned mapping (<kbd>End</kbd>)
- Select "Add Keyboard Shortcut"

[image]

Try some key combinations

[image]

Replace an existing one, or compromise

[image]

**Note**: Remapping "Move Caret to Next Word" may also help (i.e. for hopping over closing parentheses).